# Android clear activity stack and leave launcher activity in

Tags: android, android-intent, stack

I want on button press to clear the activity stack , but leave not all activities. I want to leave the launcher activity in the stack (So if the back button is pressed to go to HomeScreen).

Does:

```
Intent launch = new Intent(context, LnewActivity.class);
launch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

clear ALL activities, or does it leave the launcher activity in the stack? It is not clearly said in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it does leave the launcher Activity in the stack!

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Search.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

actually `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` searches for a allready created instance of the `Activity` in the stack and closes all `Activities` down to this one. If there is no instance of it in the stack it will clear nothing.

maybe you are looking for other flags like:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

[Android Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)